# Determine if a Java `Lock` is held by the current thread

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Suppose I have an instance of [`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

Is it possible to determine whether the lock is held by the current thread?

Assume the lock object only implements the `Lock` interface and is not necessarily reentrant, so calls to `lock` or `tryLock` may not be a good way to check the lock.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Lock` interface itself does not provide such functionality, but its common implementor, `ReentrantLock` has such method: [`ReentrantLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#isHeldByCurrentThread%28%29).

Note however, as documentation says, the main purpose of this method is debugging, assertions and testing. If you need it for normal program logic, then probably there's some better solution.

Comment: Thanks, just confirming. I currently have members declared as `Lock` type and will need to do some refactoring :)

Comment: Oh, and yes, I'm using this for assertions, deep down in program logic where I want to ensure that the proper lock is held.  Thanks for promoting good practices!